# C# and nodejs under one file

Tags: c#, node.js

I was wondering is it possible to run nodejs sever under c# code!

Currently i have `Program.exe` and `startnode.bat` (node node.js start)

I want that (node node.js start) works under Program.exe so then I don't have to run 2 applications!

Comment: You can invoke command-line processes from C# code.  Of course, node itself will still be a separate process.

Comment: http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/

Answer (score 0):

First, for clarification, your Node.js service (and server) will be running in a separate process from your C# application regardless of what you do - your C# console app won't actually be doing the hosting itself. Note, too, that you're making the batch file and your C# program part of the same *project*, not part of the same *file*.

With that said, as David indicated in the comments, you can include the .bat file as part of your C# application and do a System.Diagnostics.Process.Start on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Process the proccess class within .net (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples)

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "startnode.bat";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.Start();

// Do some stuff

myProcess.Kill();
```